# Pipe characters are being read incorrectly in python

Tags: python

I am creating a translator to produce glitched discord messages.

This glitch involves a large block of text that contains a lot of the pipe (`|`) character - below;

```
||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​||||​|| _ _ _ _ _ _
```

Because this would look pretty horrible in my code, I contain it in a second file called `glitch.txt`, and then i can store this as a variable in my code as `with open("glitch.txt", "r") as f: glitch = f.readline()`

However, there is some sort of error that occurs using this method when reading pipe characters. If I was to `print(glitch)`, I would receive the following output:

```
||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹||||â€‹|| _ _ _ _ _ _
```

I cannot think of a way to outright prevent this - any thoughts?

Thanks.

So far I haven't attempted anything at outright circumvention. Only transforming the data afterwards.

I've tried `glitch = glitch.replace("â€‹", "|")` and `glitch = glitch.replace("â€‹", "")` but neither have worked to give me the correct output as they do not work correctly within discord.

Comment: The obvious answer is that there is no error; the glitch.txt file actually contains those characters.  How did you create that file?

Comment: Which operating system?  That looks like UTF-8 data being interpreted as bytes.

Comment: It would be  `E2 80 8B`, which is the Unicode U+200B "zero width space".  My guess is you created this file in a word processor instead of a text editor.  Try creating it with a simple Python script instead.